# Copying html data from divs via AJAX to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have some divs that are created by the sites users via PHP MySQL.

I'm trying to create a copy function, so any user can look at other users data and be able to "copy" the others data to their own profile.

Here is a snippet of the divs that are being printed from my database:
(I removed the SQL stuff, to keep this post simple as possible, as this part is working as it should)

```
  echo '<div class="profilecontainer">';

     echo '<div class="profile">';
     echo '<div class="optionhover">'; ?> <a class="a" href="<?php  echo 'download.php?id='. urlencode($fil_id)?><?php echo '">Download</a></br><p><a class ="copy" href="#" onclick="copytoprofile()">Copy</a></div>';
     echo '<div class="profilehover"><div class="title">'.$title.
     '</div></br>';
     echo '<div class="date">'.$date.
     '</div></br>';
     echo 'Name: <div class="name">'.$name.
     '</div></br>';
     echo 'Category: <div class="category">'.$category.
     '</div></br>';
```

I'm new to AJAX and jQuery, and I have only been able to find guides and SO post going the other way around; getting data from a database to a page.

What I need is to get the data that is already displayed on the site copied to insert as new data into the database.

So here is my best attempt, but I know it probably it's far from being correct.. but just to show what I already tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copytotimeline() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.profilecontainer .profilehover .date').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function(){
                var date = $(this).innerHTML();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "copy.php",
                    data: { "date": date },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#display").html(result);
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    });
}

</script>
```

The above code is an attempt to get the "date" information from the div container. Ideal I would want every thing inside the container, all the variables and the file as well.

I'm guessing I then should perform the sql insert query on my copy.php page.

Comment: Your JS code is looking for an HTML element ID of `notecontainer` but that ID doesn't exist in the code you posted. Perhaps you meant `class="profilecontainer"` in your PHP code to really be `id="notecontainer"`.

Comment: _Side note:_ Instead of echoing a bunch of HTML using PHP, it's better to close the PHP block `?>`, write your HTML and then open a new PHP block `<?php` after, if needed. Then the HTML can be better formatted, easier to read and IDE's can syntax highlight the HTML as well.

Comment: @Dave I edited that, my mistake! thank you.  This mistake happened when I copied it into creating this SO post, I decided to change the names for making it more understable for my post here. However I did try my code with the correct names before posting it here.

Comment: But you still have it as a class not an ID in the HTML. The JS is never going to find it.

Comment: Please copy/paste your actual code without any rewrites. It's pretty pointless for us to help you debug a rewrite since it can (like you just noticed) introduce new issues.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know. Long story short;  I like it this way. Also that part is working successfully.  But its definitely here by noted! thank you.

Comment: @Dave I had not noticed that, I just changed it but I still don't get anything through. 
Is it the correct way I'm trying to grab the html? using innerHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function CopyDatetoProfile(mydiv){
var $this=$(mydiv);
var my_date=$this.html();
  console.log('My Date :',my_date);
  //here you can write your ajax im doing it below the script
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="date" onclick="CopyDatetoProfile(this);">12-01-2019</div>
<div class="date" onclick="CopyDatetoProfile(this);">13-01-2019</div>
<div class="date" onclick="CopyDatetoProfile(this);">14-01-2019</div>
<div class="date" onclick="CopyDatetoProfile(this);">15-01-2019</div>
</div>
```

Above code give you the text as HTML in div having class 'date'. Now you have to call ajax to post this data and to save to your database. I have taken a variable name **date** that will be reflected in your php script as an index of $_POST;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "copy.php",
    data: { date: my_date },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        $("#display").html(result);
    }
});
```

Now your php page how you will receive the data and how you will do the needful:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
     $date_to_insert=$_POST['date'];
     /*  your process */
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried implementing this and it works very good! However, it only works on the first div that are printed. Example: If there are 4 divs. If I click on div 2-4 they will all show the value from div 1. The divs are printed using a while loop. And they are created by users. So there can be infinite.

Comment: @chao Ans is updated, hope it will work the way you like.

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out the last hour from your example but without any luck. My problem is your example expects that the user clicks on the date itself. But I'm looking for clicking on a link inside a container and get data from other divs inside that container. Does that make sense to you? I appreciate your help!

Comment: I finally found out the solution. I added a: "each(function()" also added: var $this=$(this).find('.date');
Since the date is not its value but in another div inside the container.

Comment: We are passing the object "this" in the function, so we don't need to loop, if you are going to use the loop , then no need to pass the object as param in function.